# HttpClient SendAsync return unauthorized first request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

My login method logic is sending request to TokenController[AllowAnonymous] to get auth token then inject the auth token in to GetUser method by sending request to UserController[Authorized]. I tried the authorized endpoint on Postman, it works well. However, it always fails on the first request, I modified code just for testing that, if it return Unauthorized, resend the request, then it passes. I doubt that the first request httpClient.SendAsync loses the Authoriaztion headers. Anyone has suggestions?

```
public class LoginController : Controller 
{
    private string GetToken(string username, string password)
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                RequestUri = new Uri(_restServiceOptions.GetRestServiceUrl("/tokens")),
                Method = HttpMethod.Post
            };
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            httpRequestMessage.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var tokenAuthentication = new DTO.TokenAuthentication
            {
                UsernameOrEmailAddress = username.Base64Encode(),
                Password = password.Base64Encode()
            };

            var deserializeObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tokenAuthentication);

            httpRequestMessage.Content = new StringContent(deserializeObject, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            using (var response = httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result)
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    var apiResponse = JObject.Parse(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                    var jwToken = apiResponse.GetValue("Data").ToObject<string>();
                    // Problem starts from here, look at the method GetAuthUser below
                    var user = RestHelper.GetAuthUser(RestServiceOptions restServiceOptions, string jsonWebToken);
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        return user;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Exception("User not found");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

internal class RestHelper
{
    internal static DTO.User GetAuthUser(RestServiceOptions restServiceOptions, string jsonWebToken)
    {
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            RequestUri = new Uri(restServiceOptions.GetRestServiceUrl("/Users/GetJwtUser")),
            Method = HttpMethod.Get
        };
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + jsonWebToken);
        // Always get unauthorized after the first time request sent by SendAsync
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result)
        {
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var apiResponse = JObject.Parse(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                return apiResponse.GetValue("Data").ToObject<DTO.User>();
            }
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                // Resend the request by GetAsync if unauthorized just for testing 
                // This second time request sent, it passes
                var resendRes = httpClient.GetAsync(httpRequestMessage.RequestUri).Result;
                if (resendRes.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                   var resendApiResponse = JObject.Parse(resendRes.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                   var user = resendApiResponse.GetValue("Data").ToObject<DTO.User>();
                }

                throw new Exception("Unauthorized");
            }
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                throw new Exception("NotFound");
            }
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotModified)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: `httpClient` in `RestHelper` is not the same `httpClient` in `LoginController`.

Comment: Also, read [this article](https://josefottosson.se/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/) and [this article](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Comment: @John so you mean they are different instances? Thanks for those links btw

Comment: That's exactly what I mean, yes.

Comment: @John But I merged two methods into one with the same httpClient instance (`var httpClient = new HttpClient()`), it did not work either.